# Create Tiles for dynamically switch between simple Styles

Tags: qgis, postgis, vector-tiles

My goal is to display a map that can dynamically switch between very simple styles that I will create myself. The styles should only differ in color and stroke width. If possible, I would like to use 3d. I think Vectortiles are ideal for this because I also want to print the maps and styles will be simple. The data does not have to be very current. I would like to update it once a month.

What have I done so far?

I have been working through a [blog post](https://blog.astrid-guenther.de/en/maplibre-vector-tiles-self-host/) on creating vectortiles. In the example, the PBF file was converted to a mbtiles file using tilemaker.
For a geographically small area this is great. But if I want to render the whole world, my RAM is not enough. Not even if I only want to render the country borders.
While searching, I came across another tool: [Planetiler](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planetiler). This one also requires a lot of RAM.

I was thinking if transferring the PBF file to a database would help. So I read the PDF ["Vector Tiles with PostGIS and QGIS"](https://wheregroup.com/fileadmin/wheregroup/resources/images/news/fossgis-update-2021-vector-tiles-ogr2ogr-pg_tileserv-aemde.pdf) where the PBF file is first loaded into a database before the Vectortiles are created. I'm not familiar with QGis yet and can't find instructions on exactly how this works.

My Question: Can someone give me a link that helps me to implement this variant.

Comment: As per the [Tour], we have a One question per Question policy, so bullet lists of questions are going to generate close votes. But both your questions solicit opinions, which is also a close reason. GIS SE is a *problem-solving* site; not a discussion forum. In theory, we have [Chat] for discussion, but Chat has a minimum reputation requirement, and doesn't get even a shadow of the volume of the Q&A site.

Answer (score 1):

The pdf is quite detailled, I think you get the right direction. If you want to serve the whole world you will need a server, preferably Postgis, and a tool to serve vector tiles, like [pg_tileserve](https://github.com/CrunchyData/pg_tileserv). They use QGIS which is a good choice for testing, but there is a lot of options to display MVT: [link](https://github.com/mapbox/awesome-vector-tiles/). In the pdf they add a cache server in front of pg_tileserv which is a good choice too for performance.

You will need an importer to put your data into postgis. For OSM data, you got a lot of choices, like osm2pgsql, or imposm, or osmium, osmosis, ...

I personnally prefer [imposm](https://imposm.org/docs/imposm3/latest/) because it's simple to only import what you want, but there is a lot of choices for you.

You will need to import the data that you want, and probably process it (with SQL requests) to have in the proper format (for example usually you at least separate polygons, lines and points in different tables, and depending your use case you can separate more). Also make sure to have [proper indexes](http://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/indexing.html) on your tables.

You should work with a small sample first because processing can be quite long. Process the whole world will always be very difficult, and you can have memory issues quite fast, you usually need a big server to work with it ([recommandations on switch2osm](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/) talk about 1To and 24Gb RAM to serve the world), so maybe you should try to find a more specific source of data with only what you want. If you use OSM data there is a lot of sources and ways to get extracts.

Also, on a second time, for performance reasons you also will probably need to have several tables with different precision for the different zoom levels (for example the country borders don't need full precision when you are at the zoom level of a continent. With pg_tileserve [you can make function](https://github.com/CrunchyData/pg_tileserv#function-layer-examples) and use the zoom level to switch between tables. You can also use this to not send every data depending on the zoom level (or even custom parameters).